# How come my merged changesets are reappearing when doing reverse integration?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfvc

Maybe its a confusing title but the scenario is this one - we have two branches; DEV -> QA. When tests are done people merge their changesets from DEV into QA one by one. All fine. The strange thing is that a small number of merged changesets are appearing in Merge wizard when we attempt to do reverse integration QA -> DEV. If I pick one for the merge, pending change shows that files are checked out with an 'merge,edit' tag but when compared to latest there are no differences.

Obviously we need to fix this since the list keeps getting longer and longer. But, I would like to understand why is this happening in the first place. Then, how to fix this situation.

We're using TFS 2015 server and Visual Studio 2015. No 3rd party tools.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to merge back, the changeset reappears is because when TFS does a merge, it bases the merge on prior merge history, not on the actual contents of the source and target files.

If you have such request, you can use `tf merge /discard` command to update the merge history, which does not perform the merge operation. This discards a changeset from being used for a particular merge.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/merge-command?view=azure-devops

Comment: I do not understand how this could help me? My question pertains to the source control merge wizard which shows changesets that were forwarded to the branch when selecting changesets for reverse integration.

Comment: Could you please provide some screenshots to your issue?

Comment: A concrete example: 1. I have created changeset 97645 in DEV branch. 2. I have forwarded this changeset into QA using merge wizard thus creating changeset 97646. Simple. But, when I run merge wizard with QA as the source and DEV as the target, merge wizard is offering me 97646 changeset as a candidate. I have checked, changeset 97646 has no additional files or changes than 97645. Why does TFS is showing me this changeset?

Comment: I've gotten your problem. It's because when TFS does a merge, it bases the merge on prior merge history, not on the actual contents of the source and target files. Why do you want to merge back?

Comment: I do not want to merge back. TFS offering this is confusing me. We do reverse integration for the bugs HOTFIX -> QA -> DEV. So we are seeing lots of changeset when were integrating fixes into DEV branch. Do you have a suggestion how to avoid this issue? I could perform entire branch merge to resolve issue but this changesets will keep appearing.

Comment: You can use `tf merge /discard` command to update the merge history, which does not perform the merge operation. This discards a changeset from being used for a particular merge. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/merge-command?view=azure-devops.

Comment: It is not. :( I'm was already familiar with the discard option. Purpose was to understand what is happening here and how to avoid it. That would be preferable option.

Comment: This issue usually caused by you edited both branches before. You can reproduce this issue by changing the same code on two branches, check them in, and merge from branch 1 to branch 2. Then when you try merge from branch 2 to branch 1, you'll see the candidates list there. If you follow a normal process, edit branch 1 and merge to branch 2, edit branch 2 and merge branch 1, you won't have this issue.